# Переход на новую строку при записи в файл

Tags: php

Имеется такой код:

```
$handle=fopen("config/settingsConfig.ini","w");
$buffer = 'domen = "'.$_POST['domen'].'";';
fwrite($handle, $buffer.'\r\n');
$buffer = 'vkGroup = "'.$_POST['vkGroup'].'";';
fwrite($handle, $buffer.PHP_EOL);
fclose($handle);
```

В файле в итоге получается такая запись:

```
*domen = "fsdаыв";\r\nvkGroup = "fsfgdfgdg";*
```

Как реализовать переход на другую строку?

Comment: И Вас с наступающим, хочется именно в fwrite?, пробовали добавить в $buffer = 'domen = "'.$_POST['domen'].'";\n';?   Так же можно использовать nl2br() или fwrite($handle, $buffer."\n");

Comment: все эти варианты пробовал, все равно не переходитна новую строку =/
fwrite не обязателен, если есть альтернатива можно поменять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лови, протестировал. Всё оказалось проще. 
 Заменить '\r\n' на "\r\n"

```
$_POST['domen'] = 'Happy';
$_POST['vkGroup'] = 'New Year Helldrg';

$handle=fopen("text.txt","w");
$buffer = 'domen = "'.$_POST['domen'].'";';
fwrite($handle, $buffer."\r\n");
$buffer = 'vkGroup = "'.$_POST['vkGroup'].'";';
fwrite($handle, $buffer."\r\n");
fclose($handle);
```

Удачного праздника )

Comment: А ещё лучше использовать PHP_EOL так как для разных ОС он будет свой.